# Make a script executable in bin directory ant

Tags: ant, exec, chmod

Here is my ant script that wants to convert the script to executable from a zip. Here is what I do:

- unzip a .zip file,
- store to temp directory
- run the script 'pkg' with a argument validate

```
<chmod dir="tmp/temp/test/bin" perm="ugo+rx" includes="**/*"  />

<echo message="Making scripts exec: tmp/temp/test/bin" />

<exec executable="/bin/bash">
    <arg value="tmp/temp/test/bin/pkg"/>
    <arg value="validate"/>
</exec>
```

This does not make the script executable and instead gives this error:

```
 Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\tmp\temp\test\bin": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied.
```

Comment: which OS are you running?

Comment: windows but this script will run on all OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot run program "D:\tmp\temp\test\bin": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied.

Are you running this under Windows or Linux/Unix/MacOS?

Windows doesn't have the concept of *executability* in a file. Instead, it associates file suffixes with executable programs. For example, I could associate the `.py` suffix to be associated with the `python.exe` program. Opening `foo.py` will run that Python script under the Python executable. Change the name to `foo.pl`, and either the script won't run, or if you've associated `.pl` with `perl.exe`, will run the script under Perl.

You can add the suffix of your script to the `%PATHEXT%` environment variable which will allow you to type the file name sans extension. For example, if I added `.py` to `%PATHEXT%`, and I type in `foo` into the command line terminal, Windows may look for `foo.py` and then execute that. (unless it finds `foo.exe` or `foo.bat` first. Then those would execute).

The `<chmod>` task does nothing under Windows. In the [`<chmod>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/chmod.html) man page, it states:

> Changes the permissions of a file or all files inside specified directories. ***Right now it has effect only under Unix or NonStop Kernel (Tandem)***.

Also, not all Zip implementations can store file permission and ownership information -- especially Unix style permissions and ownership. Some can, and some can't. Even if you somehow want to express the file's executability for Unix systems, it may not work.

What I recommend is to include a `<condition>` test in your script to test for the OS. Then, you can separate what to do if you're on Linux/Windows/MacOS and what you want to do on a Windows system.